# How to move frame using keys

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I wonder how to move a frame using keys.
For example:
I check if pressed key is key_down

```
if(event.keyCode == 40)
```

and i've got actual frame name using

```
window.name
```

I've already tried stuff like window.scrollTo, and window.scroll() but it doesn't work in IE 5(IE 11 in compability mode - work require, old app). Thanks for help.

Here's what i've tried.

```
if(key_down == event.keyCode && window.name == "leftFrame"){
    console.log("down key jupi");
    var maxY = window.scrollMaxY;
    window.scrollBy(0, 10);
}
```

Comment: where is your tried code

Comment: There you go my friend. I thought it was enough.

Comment: @iwannabeprogrammer does it work in other browsers (Chrome/FF/Safari/Opera?)

Comment: Very hard to tell because app ain't work in modern browsers. (i will work on it in the future :D)